# Ansible - Download latest release binary from Github repo

Tags: url, github, download, automation, ansible

With Ansible please advise how i could download the latest release binary from Github repository. As per my current understanding the steps would be:
a. get URL of latest release
b. download the release

For a. I have something like which does not provide the actual release (ex. v0.11.53):

```
 - name: get latest Gogs release
  local_action:
    module: uri
    url: https://github.com/gogits/gogs/releases/latest
    method: GET
    follow_redirects: no
    status_code: 301
    register: release_url
```

For b. I have the below which works but needs constant updating. Instead of version i would need a variable set in a.:

```
- name: download latest
    become: yes
    become-user: "{{gogs_user}}"
    get_url:
     url: https://github.com/gogs/gogs/releases/download/v0.11.53/linux_amd64.tar.gz
    dest: "/home/{{gogs_user}}/linux_amd64.tar.gz"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Github has an API to manipulate the release which is [documented](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-the-latest-release).

so imagine you want to get the latest release of ansible (which belong to the project ansible) you would

- call the url `https://api.github.com/repos/ansible/ansible/releases/latest`
- get an json structure like this

> ```
> {
>   "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/ansible/ansible/releases/5120666",
>   "assets_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/ansible/ansible/releases/5120666/assets",
>   "upload_url": "https://uploads.github.com/repos/ansible/ansible/releases/5120666/assets{?name,label}",
>   "html_url": "https://github.com/ansible/ansible/releases/tag/v2.2.1.0-0.3.rc3",
>   "id": 5120666,
>   "node_id": "MDc6UmVsZWFzZTUxMjA2NjY=",
>   "tag_name": "v2.2.1.0-0.3.rc3",
>   "target_commitish": "devel",
>   "name": "THESE ARE NOT OUR OFFICIAL RELEASES",
>   ...
>   },
>   "prerelease": false,
>   "created_at": "2017-01-09T16:49:01Z",
>   "published_at": "2017-01-10T20:09:37Z",
>   "assets": [
>
>   ],
>   "tarball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/ansible/ansible/tarball/v2.2.1.0-0.3.rc3",
>   "zipball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/ansible/ansible/zipball/v2.2.1.0-0.3.rc3",
>   "body": "For official tarballs go to https://releases.ansible.com\n"
> }
> ```

- get the value of the key `tarball_url`
- download the value of the key retrieved just above

In ansible code that would do

```
- hosts: localhost                                                     
  tasks:                                                               

  - uri:                                                               
      url: https://api.github.com/repos/ansible/ansible/releases/latest
      return_content: true                                             
    register: json_reponse                                             

  - get_url:                                                           
      url: "{{ json_reponse.json.tarball_url }}"                       
      dest: ./ansible-latest.tar.gz
```

I let you adapt the proper parameters to answer your question :)

Comment: The original question asked about getting the release binary, this answer appears to focus on getting the source tarball. Ansible doesn't release binaries via Github, but the project mentioned in the original question ( https://github.com/gogs/gogs/releases/ ) does. To get at these you have to go deeper into the JSON tree, and because projects that do this often to it for multiple platforms you have to also filter for the ones you want as the API will return each binary asset whereas there is only one source tarball.

Answer (score 14):

I am using the following recipe to download and extract latest `watchexec` binary for Linux from GitHub releases.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost                                                     
  tasks:                                                               

  - name: check latest watchexec
    uri:
      url: https://api.github.com/repos/watchexec/watchexec/releases/latest
      return_content: true
    register: watchexec_latest

  - name: "installing watchexec {{ watchexec_latest.json.tag_name }}"
    loop: "{{ watchexec_latest.json.assets }}"
    when: "'x86_64-unknown-linux-musl.tar.xz' in item.name"
    unarchive:
      remote_src: yes
      src: "{{ item.browser_download_url }}"
      dest: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/bin/"
      keep_newer: yes
      extra_opts:
      - --strip=1
      - --no-anchored
      - watchexec
```

`tar` `extra_opts` explained [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-extracting-specific-files/).

This still downloads the binary every time a playbook is called. As an improvement, it might be possible to use [`set_fact`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/set_fact_module.html) for caching `node_id` attribute that corresponds to the unpacked file.

Answer (score 10):

Another approach is to use ansible [github_release module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/github_release_module.html) to get the latest tag

example

```yaml
- name: Get gogs latest tag 
  github_release:
    user: gogs
    repo: gogs
    action: latest_release
  register: gogs_latest 

- name: Grab gogs latest binaries 
  unarchive: 
    src: "https://github.com/gogs/gogs/releases/download/{{ gogs_latest['tag'] }}/gogs_{{ gogs_latest['tag'] | regex_replace('^v','') }}_linux_amd64.zip"
    dest: /usr/local/bin
    remote_src: true
```

- The regex part at the end is for replacing the **v** at the beginning of the tag since the format now on GitHub for gogs is gogs_0.12.3_linux_armv7.zip and latest tag includes a **v**

Comment: It returns a `Failed` and a `changed` properties as well. What do these two signify?

Answer (score 2):

I got inspired and extended the play.
After downloading I add the version number to the binary and link to the program.
so I can check on the next run if the version is still up to date. Otherwise it is downloaded and linked again.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  vars:
    org: watchexec
    repo: watchexec
    filename: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.tar.xz
    version: latest
    project_url: https://api.github.com/repos/{{ org }}/{{ repo }}/releases
  tasks:

  - name: check {{ repo }} version
    uri:
      url: "{{ project_url }}/{{ version }}"
      return_content: true
    register: latest_version

  - name: check if {{ repo }}-{{ version }} already there
    stat:
      path: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/.local/bin/{{ repo }}-{{ latest_version.json.tag_name }}"
    register: newestbinary

  - name: download and link to version {{ version }}
    block:
      - name: create tempfile
        tempfile:
          state: directory
          suffix: dwnld
        register: tempfolder_1

      - name: "installing {{ repo }} {{ latest_version.json.tag_name }}"
        # idea from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62672308/886659
        loop: "{{ latest_version.json.assets }}"
        when: "filename|string in item.name"
        unarchive:
          remote_src: yes
          src: "{{ item.browser_download_url }}"
          dest: "{{ tempfolder_1.path }}"
          keep_newer: yes
          extra_opts:
          - --strip=1
          - --no-anchored
          - "{{ repo }}"

      - name: command because no mv available
        command: mv "{{ tempfolder_1.path }}/{{ repo }}" "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/.local/bin/{{ repo }}-{{ latest_version.json.tag_name }}"
        args:
          creates: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/.local/bin/{{ repo }}-{{ latest_version.json.tag_name }}"

      - name: "link {{ repo }}-{{ latest_version.json.tag_name }} -> {{ repo }} "
        file:
          src: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/.local/bin/{{ repo }}-{{ latest_version.json.tag_name }}"
          dest: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/.local/bin/{{ repo }}"
          state: link
          force: yes
    when: not newestbinary.stat.exists
    always:
      - name: delete {{ tempfolder_1.path|default("tempfolder") }}
        file:
          path: "{{ tempfolder_1.path }}"
          state: absent
        when: tempfolder_1.path is defined
        ignore_errors: true

# vim:ft=yaml.ansible:
```

[here is the file on github](https://github.com/ThorstenS-linux/modern-cli-tools/blob/main/tool_watchexec.yml)

Answer (score 1):

Download the latest release with the help of `json_query`.
Note: you might need `to_json|from_json` as a workaround for this [issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/27299).

```
- name: get the latest release details
  uri:
    url: https://api.github.com/repos/prometheus/node_exporter/releases/latest
    method: GET
  register: node_exp_release
  delegate_to: localhost

- name: set the release facts
  set_fact:
    file_name: "{{ node_exp_latest.name }}"
    download_url: "{{ node_exp_latest.browser_download_url }}"
  vars:
    node_exp_latest: "{{ node_exp_release.json|to_json|from_json|json_query('assets[?ends_with(name,`linux-amd64.tar.gz`)]')|first }}"

- name: download the latest release
  get_url:
    url: "{{ download_url }}"
    dest: /tmp/
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing. Debian doesn't yet have a package for github3.py and I was hesitant to install it via pip. Your solution provided an elegant workaround to using the community.general.github_release Ansible module.

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/github_release_module.html#requirements states, it needs `github3.py >= 1.0.0a3` so your comment may not be correct, @JineshChoksi

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation but they didn't use releases, so I found this workaround - it feels more hacky than it should be, but it gets the latest tag and uses that in lieu of releases when they don't exist.

```
- name: set headers more location
  set_fact: 
    headers_more_location: /srv/headers-more-nginx-module

- name: git clone headers-more-nginx-module
  git:
    repo: https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module
    dest: "{{ headers_more_location }}"
    depth: 1
    update: no

- name: get new tags from remote
  command: "git fetch --tags"
  args:
    chdir: "{{ headers_more_location }}"

- name: get latest tag
  command: "git rev-list --tags --max-count=1"
  args:
    chdir: "{{ headers_more_location }}"
  register: tags_rev_list

- name: get latest tag name
  command: "git describe --tags {{ tags_rev_list.stdout }}"
  args:
    chdir: "{{ headers_more_location }}"
  register: latest_tag

- name: checkout the latest version
  command: "git checkout {{ latest_tag.stdout }}"
  args:
    chdir: "{{ headers_more_location }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Needed to download the latest docker-compose release from github, so came up with the solution below. I know there are other ways to do this, because the latest release content that is returned also contains a direct download link for example. However, I found this solution quite elegant.

```
- name: Get all docker-compose releases
  uri:
    url: "https://api.github.com/repos/docker/compose/releases/latest"
    return_content: yes
  register: release

- name: Set latest docker-compose release
  set_fact:
    latest_version: "{{ release.json.tag_name }}"

- name: Install docker-compose
  get_url:
    url : "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/{{ latest_version }}/docker-compose-linux-{{ ansible_architecture }}"
    dest: /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
    mode: '755'
```