# aws-iam-authenticator install via ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

Looking how to translate (properly) from a bash command (orig inside a Dockerfile) to ansible task/role that will download latest aws-iam-authenticator binary and install into /usr/local/bin on Ubuntu (x64) OS.

currently I have:

`curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/kubernetes-sigs/aws-iam-authenticator/releases/latest | grep "browser_download.url.*linux_amd64" | cut -d : -f 2,3 | tr -d '"' | wget -O /usr/local/bin/aws-iam-authenticator -qi - && chmod 555 /usr/local/bin/aws-iam-authenticator`

Comment: I have updated the answer with a working example

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to write a playbook and separate that command in various tasks

Example `example.yml` file

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - shell: |
      curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/kubernetes-sigs/aws-iam-authenticator/releases/latest
    register: json
  - set_fact:
      url: "{{ (json.stdout | from_json).assets[2].browser_download_url }}"
  - get_url:
      url: "{{ url }}"
      dest: /usr/local/bin/aws-iam-authenticator-ansible
      mode: 0555
```

you can execute it by doing

```
ansible-playbook --become example.yml
```

I hope this is what you're looking for ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the information you provided. The only issue I see is that I can't guarantee that the browser_url_download is always the 3rd entry `[2]` in the array. I've posted my answer to alleviate that issue after a lot of research.

Answer (score 1):

So after finding other posts that gave strong hints, information and unresolved issues, [Ansible - Download latest release binary from Github repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50966777/ansible-download-latest-release-binary-from-github-repo#comments-50967391) & https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/27299#issuecomment-331068246. I was able to come up with the following ansible task that works for me.

```
   - name: Get latest url for linux-amd64 release for aws-iam-authenticator
     uri:
       url: https://api.github.com/repos/kubernetes-sigs/aws-iam-authenticator/releases/latest
       return_content: true
       body_format: json
     register: json_response

   - name: Download and install aws-iam-authenticator
     get_url:
       url:  " {{ json_response.json | to_json | from_json| json_query(\"assets[?ends_with(name,'linux_amd64')].browser_download_url | [0]\") }}"
       mode: 555
       dest: /usr/local/bin/aws-iam-authenticator
```

Answer (score 0):

[Note](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/install-aws-iam-authenticator.html)
If you're running the AWS CLI version 1.16.156 or later, then you don't need to install the authenticator. Instead, you can use the [aws eks get-token](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/eks/get-token.html) command. For more information, see [Create kubeconfig manually](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-kubeconfig.html#create-kubeconfig-manually).