# Download latest release binary from private github project using ansible

Tags: ansible

I have binary file attached to my github release. Repository is private. I can download binary with curl using following

```
curl -O \
  --url https://github.com/myproject/releases/download/main-db24b21d/binary \
  --header 'Authorization: Basic <token>'
```

I am tyring to do the same in ansible by adapting [very similar question asked in Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50966777/ansible-download-latest-release-binary-from-github-repo). However, I can't make `get_url` to download binary. I have following part in ansible

```
    - name: Download binary from Github
      get_url:
       url: "https://github.com/myproject/releases/download/main-db24b21d/binary"
       dest: "/home/user/server"
       force_basic_auth: yes
       username: <username>
       password: <password>
```

I also tried

```
    - name: Download binary from Github
      get_url:
       url: "https://github.com/myproject/releases/download/main-db24b21d/binary"
       dest: "/home/user/server"
       headers:
         Authorization: <token>
```

I can download using `get_url` when repository is public. Can anybody point out what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

So I aws using browser_download_url, it works with curl but it doesn't work with get_url I am not sure why, I check Github api documentation and try to get the binary through assets enpoint and it seems it

```
    - name: downloading binary 
      get_url:
         url: "https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{project}/releases/assets/{id} "
         dest: "/home/build"
         username: ""
         password: ""
         force_basic_auth: yes
         headers:
           accept: "application/octet-stream"
      tags:
        - api_
```